# admin-on-rest: implement a login page with a link to a registration page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, admin-on-rest

I am trying to implement a login page in admin on rest with a link to a registration form. I am quite a newbie in react and frontend development in general.

I duplicated the login page from the admin on rest demo, but I can't figure out how to add the link in the bottom. I tried adding a  component from react-router but I keep getting all sorts of errors. Is there any example I can follow?

EDIT: I am trying to add a registration page with a custom route but the page is displayed inside the admin UI. This is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot of the registration UI]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

admin-on-rest is a frontend framework but it's also a bunch of components you can use/integrate in your own app.

It's important to understand how react is working to work with admin-on-rest. 
Afaik you have to know about redux, redux-form, react-router and redux-saga.

There is a short description how to [add a login page](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html#adding-a-login-page) and 
[how to customize the login page](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authentication.html#customizing-the-login-and-logout-components).

But this is not an example.

[Here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/Login.js) is the source code of the login page. If you really want to duplicate the page you can add a link to the registration page in the render method.

First create a file called

> login.js

and duplicate the original login page. Import the Link-Component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Afterwards use the Link somewhere, for example between                         `</form>` and `</Card>` (between line 106 and 107).

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/register"}} >Registration</Link>
```

In your

> app.js

import your created login page:

```
import Login from './login';
```

and use it:

```
<Admin loginPage={Login} authClient={authClient} restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
```

EDIT:

Now you have a "Registration"-Link in your Login page.

Now, it's time to create the registration page. I am not a admin-on-rest expert, but I think the idea of admin-on-rest is to show always the menu and check the authorization. I think the most of the admin app's will not have a registration page, which must be visible for users which have not logged in and they should not see the menu on the left side. It's similar to a login page. So you have to create custom route to a custom page (without a authorization check) with a custom layout.

Create a new file called

> MyLayout.js

with the content of

[Layout.js](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/layout/Layout.js)

and remove the lines

```
injectTapEventPlugin()
```

and

```
<Sidebar>
  {menu}
</Sidebar>
```

to hide the menu on the left side.

Then create a file called

> customRoutes.js

with the following content:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Register from './Register';

export default [
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
];
```

and a file called

> Register.js

with

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import { ViewTitle } from 'admin-on-rest';

const Register = () => (
    <Card>
        <ViewTitle title="Register" />
        <CardText>             
            <div>This is the register page.</div>
        </CardText>
    </Card>
);

export default Register;
```

In your

> app.js:

```
import MyLayout from './MyLayout';
import customRoutes from './customRoutes';
import MyLayout from './MyLayout';
import authClient from './authClient';


<Admin appLayout={MyLayout} loginPage={Login} authClient={authClient} customRoutes={customRoutes} restClient={myApiRestClient}>
```

This is just an (ugly) example.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar to what you suggested, but the problem is that I am getting a page which looks similar to the other admin-on-rest pages which are displayed after login. I want it to display just my page and not all the other stuff. I looked at the admin-on-rest code and I am thinking about writing my own Admin component which will have a special case for the registration page like the original component has for the login page. This seems pretty ugly, is there a better way?

Comment: @barisdad Can you give me some more information? What do you mean with "all the other stuff"? The navigation drawer on the left side? The search- and filters on lists? ... If you don't want or need to use the typical CRUD components of admin-on-rest I think it would be easier to write a plain react app. There are a lot of boilerplates on github to make it easier to start with react.

Comment: By the way, using <Admin> and <Resource> is completely optional. If you feel like bootstrapping a redux app yourself, it’s totally possible. (from the offical docu: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html).

Comment: I do want to use all these components, just not in the registration page and not in the login page. I'll edit my question and add a screenshot of the registration form.

Comment: I wrote my own version of Admin and it works, but your solutions seems more elegant since it enables me to use admin-on-rest components. Did you test it? I may change my code accordingly.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes I tested it. Another solution is to generate a own Admin component and add a fixed route "/register" similar to "/login"... When my example is working and your question is answered, please mark the answer as correct. :)

Comment: How is it that the login page does not have the AppBar or Menu but everything else does?